# Excel VBA Selecting Multiple columns with last row and apply Condition Format

Tags: excel, vba, colors, conditional-formatting

Can someone help me on my below query. I'm trying to Select Multiple columns with last row and applying Condition Format but it is not working in the way I'm trying.

Working One:

```
Dim lr As Long

With Range("E:E,F:F,H:H")
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=0"
    .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    .FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = 13561798
    .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End With
```

This one is not working :

```
Dim lr As Long

    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

With Range(""E2:E" & lr,"F2:F" & lr,"H2:H" & lr)
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=0"
    .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    .FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = 13561798
    .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End With
```

And I'm trying to apply color to a cell that contains error "#N/A" but it is not working.

```
Dim lr As Long

    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

With Range(""E2:E" & lr,"F2:F" & lr,"H2:H" & lr)
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=#N/A"
    .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    .FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = 13561798
    .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End With
```

Any help one above 2 queries would be appreciated..

Comment: You're still using `.FormatConditions(1)` even after adding >1 condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Sub Test()
    Dim lr As Long, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'for example
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    With ws.Range("E2:E" & lr & ",F2:F" & lr & ",H2:H" & lr)
        With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlCellValue, _
                                   Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=0")
            .SetFirstPriority
            .Interior.Color = 13561798
            .StopIfTrue = False
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

`FormatConditions.Add` returns the just-added condition, so you can use that in a `With` block.  Also fixed your `Range()` call.

For #N/A

```
With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=isNA(E2)")
```

Comment: Thanks.. that is what I'm expecting. Could you please help me on my second query aswell ? "And I'm trying to apply color to a cell that contains error "#N/A" but it is not working."

Comment: Thanks @Tim Williams for you help and ideas. Your answers helped my issues and I've used isError instead of isNA (not sure but isNA is not working for my code but it might be useful for others). Thanks much for your response.